# AJAX Pagination jQuery-2.1.4.min.js: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, templates, pagination

i am working with this ajax Pagination in Codeigniter HMVC. i get the output i wanted.. BUT only on the first link. then after that, the next pages dont open. or when i click them nothing happens. i checked the element and it has errors.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of http://http://localhost/TLC_HR/Job_Titles/ajaxPaginationData/10 500 (Internal Server Error)
jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4 POST http://localhost/TLC_HR/Job_Titles/ajaxPaginationData/10 500 (Internal Server Error)k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4n.extend.ajax @ jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4n.(anonymous function) @ jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4onclick @ Job_Titles:524
```

here are my codes.

Job_Titles.php - controller

```
<?php

class Job_Titles extends MY_Controller{

    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Job_Titles_Model');
        $this->load->library('Ajax_pagination');
        $this->perPage = 10;

    }

// VIEW REDIRECTING /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public function index(){

    /// view ajax config/////

    $data = array();

    //total row count
    $totalRec = count($this->Job_Titles_Model->getRows());

    //configuration
    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config['div'] = 'postList'; //parent div tag id
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'Job_Titles/ajaxPaginationData';
    $config['total_rows'] = $totalRec;
    $config['per_page'] = $this->perPage; 

    $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);

    //get data // must pass this to $this->load->view('content_view') and make it $this->load->view('content_view',$data,false)
    $data['job_titles'] = $this->Job_Titles_Model->getRows(array('limit'=>$this->perPage,$this->uri->segment(3)));

    $data['content_view'] = 'Job_Titles/jobtitles_read';
    $this->templates->admin_template($data);

    }

    public function add_view(){

    $data['content_view'] = 'Job_Titles/add_view';
    $this->templates->admin_template($data);

    }

//// pagination

    public function ajaxPaginationData(){

    $page = $this->input->post('page');
        if(!$page){
            $offset = 0;
        }else{
            $offset = $page;
        }

        //total row count
        $totalRec = count($this->Job_Titles_Model->getRows());

        //pagination config
        $config['first_link'] = 'First';
        $config['div'] = 'postList'; //parent div tag id
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'Job_Titles/ajaxPaginationData';
        $config['total_rows'] = $totalRec;
        $config['per_page'] = $this->perPage; 

        $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);

        //get post data

        $data['job_titles'] = $this->Job_Titles_Model->getRows(array('start'=>$offset,'limit'=>$this->perPage));

        //load the view
        $data['content_view'] = "'Job_Titles/jobtitles_read', $data, false";
        $this->templates->admin_template($data);

    }

}

?>
```

Job_Titles_Model.php --  model

```
<?php

class Job_Titles_Model extends CI_Model{

    function __construct() {
        $this->table = 'job_titles';
    }
/////  VIEW PAGINATION /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        public function getRows($params = array()){

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($this->table);

        if(array_key_exists("start", $params) && array_key_exists("limit", $params)){

            $this->db->limit($params['limit'],$params['start']);
        }elseif (!array_key_exists("start", $params) && array_key_exists("limit", $params)) {
            $this->db->limit($params['limit']);
        }

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return ($query->num_rows() > 0)?$query->result_array():FALSE;
    }



}


?>
```

admin_template.php --- template

```
          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Job_Titles"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Job Titles</a>
          </li>
          <div class="box-body">    
              <?php $this->load->view($content_view); ?>
          </div>
```

and add_view.php --- where pagination will show.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap/css/inputfield.css">

<div>
    <center>
        <fieldset>


                <?php

                    echo form_open('Job_Titles/create');
                ?>

                <p>
                    <label class="field" for="JOB_CODE"><span>*</span>Job Code:</label>
                    <input type = "text" name="JOB_CODE" class ="textbox-300">
                    <label class = "error"><?php echo form_error("JOB_CODE"); ?></label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="field" for="JOB_NAME"><span>*</span>Job Name:</label>
                    <input type = "text" name="JOB_NAME" class ="textbox-300">
                    <?php echo form_error("JOB_NAME"); ?>
                </p>



                <?php
                    echo form_submit('submit','Save');
                    echo form_close();
                ?>



        </fieldset>
    </center>
</div>
```

Comment: does this really work ? $data['content_view'] = "'Job_Titles/jobtitles_read', $data, false"; and then in your view <?php $this->load->view($content_view); ?>

i cannot imagine that

Comment: no. haha. it read it as 'Job_Titles/jobtitles_read', $data, false.php haha. but i need something like `$this->load->view($content_view,$data,false)`.. maybe you can help me with that. thats one of the possible errors that i think

Answer (score 0):

i've to give an answer base on my comment (i will extend my answer based on your reply because we have to start somewhere to clean this mess ;))

first of all in your Job Titles Controller replace the part with your content view as a string with the following line of code

```
$data['content_view'] = array(
    "url" => "Job_Titles/jobtitles_read",
    "data" => $data,
    "blnReturnAsAString" => false
);
```

and in your view you should write this

```
$this->load->view($content_view["url"], $content_view["data"], $content_view["blnReturnAsAString"]);
```